# I have the method below that gets a two-dimensional array and a value. The method check if the value be in the array or not

Tags: java, arrays, binary-search

I have the method below that gets a two-dimensional array and a value. The method check if the value be in the array or not.

I don't understand why do I need the line of code that I highlighted in bold **(if (m[i][m[i].length-1] <= val)**.

It Looks that the code works without this line as well... Why do I still need this line, can someone explain me please? thanks

```
public static boolean findValWhat (int[][] m, int val)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
        **if (m[i][m[i].length-1] <= val){**
            if (binarySearch(m[i], val) == val){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;

}
```

Comment: I suppose you waste one extra search call, given that your binary search function doesn't depend on that bound, but is still influenced by it.

Answer (score 0):

The code will still work without it but is makeing it run faster.
Lets say you have this sorted 2d array:
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
Then you can see that if you are searching for 8 you don't need to do binary search for the first line because 3 is smaller then 8 and he is the biggest number in there.
You can even make this code batter by doing binary search instead of the loop.